# Python3: using generator to process a very large list of integers

Tags: python-3.x, generator

This is from a leetcode question I am working on. The problem is the following:

create an algorithm that works in the the following fashion:

arr = [1,3,4,8], queries = [[0,1],[1,2],[0,3],[3,3]]

the output is:
[2,7,14,8]

by applying the following series of operations:
The XOR values for queries are:

[0,1] = 1 xor 3 = 2

[1,2] = 3 xor 4 = 7

[0,3] = 1 xor 3 xor 4 xor 8 = 14

[3,3] = 8

The input is a very large list for arr and an even longer list for queries. The output has to be a list and I have tried this several ways.

first attempt: (building a gigantic list in memory and returning it using append() )

```py
def XORsubqueries(array, queries):
    result = []
    for pair in queries:
        value = array[pair[0]]
        i = pair[0]
        while i < pair[1]:
            if pair[0] == pair[1]:
                result.append(array[pair[i]] ^ array[pair[i]])
                break
            else:
                i += 1
                value ^= array[i]
        result.append(value)
    return result
```

As you can imagine this takes FOREVER (53 seconds on my i5 dual core).  I then remembered about generator expressions for lazily building values and thought they might come in handy just for this kind of thing.

```py
def XORsubqueries(array, queries):
    
    result = [0] * len(array)
    def XOR(array, queries):     
        for pair in queries:
            value = array[pair[0]]
            i = pair[0]
            while i < pair[1]:
                i += 1
                value ^= array[i]
                yield value
    return list(XOR(array, queries))
```

If i remove the list off that return statement it figures it out in like 0.0001 seconds ! But I have to return it as a list.  Is there a way I can rewrite my algorithm to do what I am trying to do with this generator or did I paint myself into a corner ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please format the code and add the link to the programming challenge.

Comment: Other than exceeding the time limit are there any other problems in the execution?

Comment: The time was the biggest issue.  It was a little tricky getting the loop to work right - python range() is a little funky for including the last element which is why i used a while loop as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the biggest slowdowns are the `append` and `list` functions. In your second example, you attempt to pre-create a list, which is a good idea, but a) you use the wrong size, and b) you never use the created list. Here's an example using a pre-made list:

```
def xor_subqueries(array, queries):
    result = [0] * len(queries)
    for i,q in enumerate(queries):
        val = array[q[0]]
        for j in range(q[0]+1, q[1]+1):
            val ^= array[j]
        result[i] = val
    return result
```

Pretty straight forward. I'm not so sure this task calls for a generator function, but here's an example of using one:

```
def xor_subqueries(array, queries):
    def genx():
        for q in queries:
            val = array[q[0]]
            for j in range(q[0]+1, q[1]+1):
                val ^= array[j]
            yield val

    result = [0] * len(queries)
    for i,q in enumerate(genx()):
        result[i] = q
    return result
```

However, I have read that list comprehension is faster. You could easily re-write the above function using list comprehension (`return [x for x in genx()]`), but here is an example using the built-in functions `reduce` and `xor` which stand-in for your generator function.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

def xor_subqueries(array, queries):
    return [reduce(xor, array[q[0]:q[1]+1], 0) for q in queries]
```

It calls `reduce` on the sub-list `array[q[0]:q[1]+1])`. `reduce` calls `xor` on each element of the sub-list with the previously calculated value and an initial value of `0`.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments.  I will try each of them and see how they compare in runtime ! :D

Comment: Good. I am interested in knowing how they perform.

Answer (score 0):

results of benchmarking various solutions from slowest to fastest using timeit():

building a list and appending to it:  (52-55 seconds)

```
def XORsubqueries(array, queries):
result = []
for pair in queries:
    value = array[pair[0]]
    i = pair[0]
    while i < pair[1]:
        if pair[0] == pair[1]:
            result.append(array[pair[i]] ^ array[pair[i]])
            break
        else:
            i += 1
            value ^= array[i]
    result.append(value)
return result
```

homespun generator : (49 - 53 seconds) slightly faster using list() incidentally

```
def XORsubqueries(array, queries):

#result = [0] * len(array)
def XOR(array, queries):     
    for pair in queries:
        value = array[pair[0]]
        i = pair[0]
        while i < pair[1]:
            i += 1
            value ^= array[i]
            yield value

return [x for x in XOR(array, queries)] # 53 seconds
return list(XOR(array, queries)) # 49 seconds
```

using reduce (thanks @Johnny Mopp )  13 seconds

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

def xor_subqueries(array, queries):
    return [reduce(xor, array[q[0]:q[1]+1], 0) for q in queries]
```

using accumulate (thanks @StefanPochmann from leetcode)  holy crap 0.009 seconds !

```
def xorQueries(self, arr, queries):
    x = [0, *itertools.accumulate(arr, operator.xor)]
    return [x[i] ^ x[j+1] for i, j in queries]
```

I am curious to know why this last one is SO MUCH faster than the reduce.  I am guessing it has to do with using accumulate as an iterator to build the output lazily and then a list comprehension for the output as opposed to building a list comprehension (?)

Comment: Mine is faster because it handles each query with a single operation. All those little technicalities you and Johnny talk about are rather irrelevant. This problem really asks for prefix-xors.